# Trigger resize of multiple Google Maps v3 on different JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out how to pass the latitude and longitude to a google map when my page loads.  I am using the following code in the header of my page which works to generate the maps based on the hard-coded latitude and longitude:

```
var map1;
var map2;

$(document).ready(function(){

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.7620537, -79.3516683),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-1"),myOptions);

    var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.6918950,-79.5310706),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-2"),myOptions2);  
}

$("#maptabs").tabs({initialIndex:0,collapsible:true,select: function(){}});
```

In the body of the page I use the following PHP script to retrieve the correct latitude and longitude that I would like to map:

```
<?php 
    $google_maps_key='ABQIAAAAO-NJVsUOX31LQYJY1LUG8BSOYIDhzYrztjureJjDlAP7PmMi1xQsm9hQ6Z-LRdLFkCtIPr0FQBZxeQ';
    $adr = urlencode(DLookup("Property Address", "tblproperties", "`Roll#`=".$id["pntysc"]["pn"]).", ".DLookup("municipalityname", "tblmunicipalities", "municipalitiescounty=".$county));
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=".$adr."&output=xml&key=$google_maps_key";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if ($status='200') { //address geocoded correct, show results
    foreach ($xml->Response->Placemark as $node) { // loop through the responses
    $address = $node->address;
    $quality = $node->AddressDetails['Accuracy'];
    $coordinates = $node->Point->coordinates;
    echo ("Quality: $quality. $address. $coordinates<br/>");
    }
    } else { // address couldn't be geocoded show error message
    echo ("The address $adr could not be geocoded<br/>");
    }
    ?>
```

Here is my question:  How can I populate the maps using the $coordinates variable that is generated in the body of the page, when I have code in the header of the page that needs that particular value?  What is the best practice in terms of populating the maps using variable latitude and longitude instead of having those values simply hard-coded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider defining your Coordinates to display prior to displaying your header. That is, define everything your going to use in your google maps prior to anything being displayed. Place all data into arrays; $coordinates, $groups, etc. You don't have to build out an XML file. You can just use a mix of PHP to build out the Javascript used in your maps views. You can visit a WordPress example at:

http://www.dogfriendlyorlando.com/

There's an IFRAME in the page that displays the header map based on the information provided thru WordPress Posts.

```
I can't seem to paste in the entire code here.
```

Email me at jjwdesign - thru gmail and I'll send you the PHP code so you can look at it.

There's another more complex CRM example (SugarCRM - Google Maps project) at:

http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/jjwgooglemaps/

Cheers, Jeff Walters

Comment: Thanks jeff.  Have just emailed you.